# How should I break a list of tuples so that it forms lists with same keys?

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools

I have

```
iList = [('FirstParam', 1), ('FirstParam', 2), 
         ('FirstParam', 3), ('FirstParam', 4), 
         ('SecondParam', 5), ('SecondParam', 6), 
         ('SecondParam', 7)]
```

I am trying to form:

```
iList1 = [('FirstParam', 1), ('FirstParam', 2), 
         ('FirstParam', 3), ('FirstParam', 4)]

iList2 = [('SecondParam', 5), ('SecondParam', 6), 
         ('SecondParam', 7)]
```

I tried:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(iList, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print "List",(list(group))
```

it prints 2 lists the wayI wanted.
Output:

```
List [('FirstParam', 1), ('FirstParam', 2), 
         ('FirstParam', 3), ('FirstParam', 4)]
List [('SecondParam', 5), ('SecondParam', 6), 
         ('SecondParam', 7)]
```

My concern is how should i make those as iList1 and iList2?
I don't get the way `(list(group))` works and prints the list.

Comment: i think you asked similar question before. right?

Comment: @HuStmpHrr It was for different context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and unpack into `iList1` and `iList2`:

```
iList1, iList2 = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(iList, operator.itemgetter(0))]
```

Then you will get what you want:

```
>>> iList1
[('FirstParam', 1), ('FirstParam', 2), ('FirstParam', 3), ('FirstParam', 4)]
>>> iList2
[('SecondParam', 5), ('SecondParam', 6), ('SecondParam', 7)]
```